# Context changes to null outside of onCreateView method in a fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am relatively new to Android. I am writing an app that uses a fragment in the main activity. This fragment also acts like a location listener and implements the onLocationChange method. This is because, based on location changes new text views are being added to this fragment.

The onCreateView method in the fragment has its scroll view created that is added to the main activity. In the same onCreateView method, I also capture the context and the linear layout tag that is present in the fragment's layout xml where I would like to insert the text views that get created in onLocationChange method.

The issue I am seeing is the context and the layout values are null in onLocationChanged method and the updateView method. Using the debugger I confirmed that they do have non-null values in the onCreateMethod only.

Here is the code snippet for the fragment class:

```
public class ResultsFragment extends Fragment implements LocationListener,OnCompleteListener {

private LoadPlaces loadPlaces;
HashMap<String, Double> map=new HashMap<String, Double>();
LinearLayout layout;
Context context;
Activity activity;
ScrollView view;

 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    view =(ScrollView)inflater.inflate(R.layout.scroll_view, container, false);
    layout=(LinearLayout)view.findViewById(R.id.resultsView);
    context=view.getContext();

    return view;
 }

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    loadPlaces=new LoadPlaces(context); //context is null here
    loadPlaces.setOnCompleteListener(this);
    loadPlaces.execute(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
}

private void updateResultView(){
    String status=loadPlaces.getResultStatus();
    if("OK".equals(status)){
        for (Place p:loadPlaces.getPlacesResult()){
            TextView txt=new TextView(context); //context is null here
            txt.setText(p.name);
            txt.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            layout.addView(txt); //layout is null here
        }   
    }
}


@Override
public void onComplete(String result) {
    updateResultView();
}
```

here is the fragment's layout xml:

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/results"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:fillViewport="true"
android:scrollbars="vertical"
android:scrollbarAlwaysDrawVerticalTrack="true"
android:clickable="true"
android:background="@color/grey"
android:layout_marginTop="25dip">

<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/resultsView"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">                  
 </LinearLayout>
```

And this is the main activity's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="30dip" 
android:layout_gravity="center"
android:background="@color/background">
 <fragment android:name="com.app.xxx.ResultsFragment"
          android:id="@+id/headlines_fragment"
          android:layout_weight="1"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="0dp"/>
```

For your information, the activity that holds the fragment is never paused/killed. It is always visible while the location service runs in the background. So in this process, I don't think the fragment is getting destroyed.

Am i approaching this problem incorrectly? Is there a better way to access or save the fragment's context and use it later? Any tips will be helpful.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: THis is incorrect context=view.getContext(); it should be context= getActivity();

Comment: but why you need `Context context` and `Activity activity` ? `Activity` is a `Context` right...?

Comment: I am aware that activity is a context, The reason I had view.getContext, and two separate variables for activity and context is only for testing purpose since I was getting null values. I will be using only one of them eventually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change to:

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {
    if(getActivity()!=null){
    loadPlaces=new LoadPlaces(getActivity()); //context is null here
    loadPlaces.setOnCompleteListener(this);
    loadPlaces.execute(String.valueOf(location.getLatitude()),String.valueOf(location.getLongitude()));
    }
}
```

The problem is location change listener is called before `onCreateView`.

You can ignore all the onLocationChanged calls until your fragment is attached to Activity by using above function.

Answer (score 0):

```
public void onAttach(android.app.Activity activity) {
    super.onAttach(activity);
    context = (Context)getActivity();
};
```